# commons daemon - Cannot find any VM in Java Home -Java 11

Tags: java-11, apache-commons-daemon

I am trying to run a daemon service with Java 11 and getting the below error.
Cannot find any VM in Java Home

I verified the java home is set correctly.
I tried to run with Java 8 and I do not run into any issues.
I also tried installing Java 11 JDK and JRE but still running into this error.
Also tried updating common daemons to the latest version 1.3.4.